# App crashes on large screens

Tags: android

I have this function:

```
public static Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm,Context c) {

    int width =(int) dp2px(bm.getWidth(),c);
    int height = (int) dp2px(bm.getHeight(),c);
    float scaleWidth = ((float) 250) / width;
    float scaleHeight = ((float) 170) / height;

    // create a matrix for the manipulation
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    // resize the bit map
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
    // recreate the new Bitmap
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);

    return resizedBitmap;
}
```

where dp2px is:

```
private static float dp2px(int dip, Context context){
    float scale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    return dip * scale + 0.5f;
}
```

It is ok on most screens but, for example, on galaxy s3 it returns

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: x+width must be <= bitmap.width()

on this line:

```
Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);
```

Comment: Offtopic, but why don't you do this operation at the time of Bitmap decoding itself? Go through http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html decode your bitmap specifically for lower dimensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's complaining that you're trying to get a pixel outside the range of the bitmap. It could be just a rounding issue. Perhaps your calculated `width` is a pixel bigger than the actual bitmap width. What happens if you don't add the `0.5f` in your `dp2px()` function?

Answer (score 1):

use this in manifest.xml

```
 <supports-screens 
android:resizeable="true" 
android:smallScreens="true" 
android:normalScreens="true" 
android:largeScreens="true" 
android:anyDensity="true"/>
```

and

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

besides your code. have you added the support screens tag accordingly to your manifest?

Example:

```
<supports-screens android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true"     android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true"></supports-screens>
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert dp into px, you can use the following:

```
int pixels = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, (float) dp, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```